# Android - Make the background part of the Dialog available

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I am creating an AlertDialog as follows.

- I fix the dialog view to the bottom of the screen. Average width: 400, height: 200 dimensions. (Actually I want it to be something like Admob-banner)
- I always want the screen I started with show () to remain visible and the screen behind the dialog to be usable. So I made the background transparent for the user.

However, there is a problem. Dialog background cannot be clicked. How do I make the background available while the dialog remains on the screen? Also, I don't want the dialog to be closed when the user is using the background.

**TestBannerDialog.kt**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowManager

class TestBannerDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context, false, null) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.test_banner_dialog)
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

        window?.let {
            it.attributes.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
            it.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        }
       
    }
}
```

**test_banner_dialog.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp">

    <ImageView ....... />

    <TextView ....... />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @umitx why are you adding in code with your edit ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Sorry, I added it accidentally while making corrections and reviews. I lifted it back.

Comment: okey, no problem :D

Comment: This is the nature of the dialog , for what you want to achieve i suggest use a `CoordinatorLayout` with either a custom view to control the behavior or simply hardcode it in the layout file.

Comment: @Akki Yes, this good method can be used, but isn't there a method that I can use in different places without adding it to the layout, as simple as show() as in the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can use something and then add it to the layout of the screen you want it to appear.

```
class TestBannerView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context,
                                                          attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
                                                          defStyle: Int = 0,
                                                          defStyleRes: Int = 0) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyleRes) {
init {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.test_banner_view, this, true)
     }
}
```